# How to change text size of Gutenberg editor

Tags: formatting, block-editor

Is there a setting in WordPress Gutenberg editor to change the font size of the text we type while writing posts? I mean the text size inside the editor itself, not the published text that blog visitors view.

Comment: I've found what I was looking for. Here is the link to the solution in case someone is looking for this: https://www.paulchinmoy.com/change-gutenberg-editors-default-font/

Comment: Great question!  As people age, smaller type becomes hard to see...

Answer (score 8):

If you came here, like me, looking for how to adjust the available text size options within Gutenberg, you can add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file (you can add as many options as you like):

```
add_theme_support(
    'editor-font-sizes', 
    array(
        array(
            'name'      => __( 'Normal', 'your-theme-text-domain' ),
            'shortName' => __( 'N', 'your-theme-text-domain' ),
            'size'      => 14,
            'slug'      => 'normal'
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __( 'Medium', 'your-theme-text-domain' ),
            'shortName' => __( 'M', 'your-theme-text-domain' ),
            'size'      => 16,
            'slug'      => 'medium'
        )
    )
);
```

This gives the following result within the Gutenberg editor:

[image: Gutenberg editor showing custom font sizes for a paragraph in a dropdown menu]

You can add `add_theme_support( 'disable-custom-font-sizes' );` to your `functions.php` to remove the numerical input, although the "Custom" option will still be visible in the dropdown.

Comment: Is there a way to make it use em sizes instead of pixels?

Answer (score 4):

Just click on the settings/cog icon on the right hand side when you are editing paragraph. Then choose Block. You should then see the option to edit font size. You can choose from dropdown menu or type the font size you want.

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the text size inside the editor itself, not the published text. My bad, I should have been clearer. I've edited my question.

Comment: Oh haha ok sorry. Glad you have it all figured out now!

Answer (score 2):

When we change the paragraph font size in Gutenberg via the *block text settings*, it will be added inline like:

```
<p style="font-size:18px">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

If we are frequently changing the font-size (or other formatting) like that, it's easy to imagine the state of the content in few years, where most of the content formatting is hard coded.

It could e.g. override the formatting from a new theme if we decide to switch to a new theme later on.

So I would suggest using it with care.

An alternative could be to target the formatting via unobtrusive CSS.

If that's not possible one could then consider adding custom target CSS classes via the *Advanced* Gutenberg block setting:

[image]

that will generate a class attribute like:

```
<p class="some__custom--class">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

where we define the CSS class in the corresponding stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

I had same question how to change heading font size in Editor, just found myself:

PS: This is a generic solution for any WP customization:

1. While in editor, using e.g. Firefox "inspect element", select the
   element(any text or heading) you want to change;
2. In the middle column, it will point to the setting css file, e.g.
   editor-style.css,  it gives also the line number;
3. Go [SIDE MENU]Appearance => Theme Editor => select the css setting file, change the font size, and update the css setting file.
4. That's it!

For your case, it is to change **editor-blocks.css**:

```
.edit-post-visual-editor .editor-block-list__block,
.edit-post-visual-editor .editor-block-list__block p,
.editor-default-block-appender textarea.editor-default-block-appender__content {
                  font-size: 16px;   /* change to your font size */
 }
```